# How to increment a decimal stored as a varchar to the nearest scale?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a list of decimals stored as `VARCHAR(50)`, each with varying precision and scale (I have no say in the design/can't change it). I need to modify some of the numbers to be rounded up to the nearest scale (0.5 goes to 0.6, 0.001 goes to 0.002, 0.01000 goes to 0.02000, etc).

The reason being is we need to convert our boundaries for some bucketing function to decimals. Currently it is stored as:

```
'0.00', '0.05', '> 0.05'
```

But I need to convert it to all decimals:

```
'0.00', '0.05', '0.06'
```

I can get the scale of a number (5) as such:

```
SELECT LEN(CAST(REVERSE(PARSENAME('84.274190',1)) AS INT))
```

And I can get the number to be added to the value (0.00001) as such:

```
SELECT '0.' + REPLICATE('0', LEN(CAST(REVERSE(PARSENAME('84.274190',1)) AS INT))-1) + '1'
```

How can I add these two together? I can cast to `DECIMAL` but the precision, scale varies for each number.

I start with '84.274190' and I want '84.274200'

Comment: and what would 0.106 go to?

Comment: that would increment 0.107

Comment: why dont you get last element and increment it?

Comment: Sample data as DDL+DML and  desired results would increase your chances of getting a correct answer fast.

Comment: @Bharat, a lot of these numbers have trailing zero's, also what if the last non-zero digit is a 9, then we also have to increment the value before it. What if it's '0.9999'? It can go on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Interesting question.... how about this?

```
declare @table table (col varchar(16))
insert into @table
values
('0.5'),
('0.001'),
('100.01000'),
('0.1060'),
('84.274190')


select
    col
    ,cast(col as decimal(32,16)) + cast('0.' + replicate('0',len(substring(col,charindex('.',col),99)) - patindex('%[1-9]%',reverse(substring(col,charindex('.',col),99))) - 1) + '1' as decimal(32,16))
    ,left(cast(cast(col as decimal(32,16)) + cast('0.' + replicate('0',len(substring(col,charindex('.',col),99)) - patindex('%[1-9]%',reverse(substring(col,charindex('.',col),99))) - 1) + '1' as decimal(32,16)) as varchar(256)),len(cast(cast(col as decimal(32,16)) + cast('0.' + replicate('0',len(substring(col,charindex('.',col),99)) - patindex('%[1-9]%',reverse(substring(col,charindex('.',col),99))) - 1) + '1' as decimal(32,16)) as varchar(256))) - patindex('%[1-9]%',reverse(cast(cast(col as decimal(32,16)) + cast('0.' + replicate('0',len(substring(col,charindex('.',col),99)) - patindex('%[1-9]%',reverse(substring(col,charindex('.',col),99))) - 1) + '1' as decimal(32,16)) as varchar(256)))) + 1)

from
    @table
```

Comment: I know, I think the original design did not have this type of downstream use in mind. Your solution is really close. Test with '0.1990' though.

Comment: Yeah i just noticed that. One sec

Comment: check it now @TomNash

Comment: This is great. I wrapped the second column in `LEFT(..., LEN(col))` and it looks perfect.

Comment: Can you explain how you came up with `DECIMAL(32, 16)` and the `SUBSTRING(..., 99)`

Comment: I just used a large precision and scale that I would think would encompass all your values. You could check this with something like `declare @maxP int = (select max(len(right(col,len(col) - charindex('.',col)))) from @table)`

Comment: @SqlZim I'm 99.5% sure there is a simpler method haha.